# ReactJS : Maximum dept exceeded / Private Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Private route /profile rendering me an error.
My app works until I try to go on /profile.

I have never seen this error yet, so while Im searching Im posting here, maybe someone has an idea.

Also Im looking for a good documentation/tutorial on how to make private routes using jwt and js-cookie.

**error**

```
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';
import Profile from "./pages/Profile";

const App = () => {

  const [emailRegistration, setEmailRegistration] = useState("");
  const [passwordRegistration, setPasswordRegistration] = useState("");

  const [emailLogin, setEmailLogin] = useState("");
  const [passwordLogin, setPasswordLogin] = useState("");

  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);


  const register = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/signup', {
      user:{
      email: emailRegistration, 
      password: passwordRegistration
    }
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };


  const login = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login", {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user: {
      email: emailLogin,
      password: passwordLogin,
    },
  }),
})
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      console.log(res.headers.get("Authorization"));
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.headers.get("Authorization"));
      setIsAuth(true)
      return res.json();
    } else {
      return res.text().then((text) => Promise.reject(text));
    }
  })
  .then((json) => console.dir(json))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
  
  
  const getArticles = () => {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/articles", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
          } else if (res.status == "401") {
            throw new Error("Unauthorized Request. Must be signed in.");
          }
        })
        .then((json) => console.dir(json))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }

    const logout = () => {
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/logout", {
        method: "delete",
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          setIsAuth(false)
          return res.json();
        } else {
          return res.json().then((json) => Promise.reject(json));
        }
      })
      .then((json) => {
        console.dir(json);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    };

  
  const testBearer = () => {
    let cookie = Cookies.get('token');
    console.log(cookie)
  }

  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="app">

{isAuth ?
  (

    <button onClick={logout} > logout </button>
  )
  :
  (
    <div className="auth">
        <div className="registration">

          <h1> Registration </h1>

          <label> Email </label>
          <input 
            type="email" 
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEmailRegistration(e.target.value);
            }} 
          />

          <label> Password </label>
          <input 
            type="password" 
            onChange={(e) => {
              setPasswordRegistration(e.target.value);
            }} 
          />

          <button onClick={register} > Register </button>

        </div>
        <div className="login">

          <h1> Login </h1>

          <label> Email </label>
          <input 
            type="email" 
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEmailLogin(e.target.value);
            }} 
          />

          <label> Password </label>
          <input 
            type="password" 
            onChange={(e) => {
              setPasswordLogin(e.target.value);
            }} 
          />

          <button onClick={login} > Login </button>

        </div>
      </div>

  )
}
    
    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />

    <button onClick={getArticles} >getArticles </button>
    <button onClick={testBearer} >testCookie </button>
    <button onClick={logout} > logout </button>
   </div>


   <Route path="/">

    </Route>

    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} isAuth={isAuth} />


   </Router>
  )};

export default App;
```

**Profile.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const Profile = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      if you see this you entered the auth.
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Profile);
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = ({isAuth: isAuth, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
      if (isAuth) {
        return <Component />
      } else {
       return  ( 
       <Redirect to={{pathname: "/profile", state: {from: props.location }}} />
       );
      }
    }}/>
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: If `isAuth` is false, then navigating to the protected route `/profile` will endlessly redirect to itself since the fallback behaviour of `ProtectedRoute` is to redirect to `/profile`. It only makes sense for a protected route to redirect to a public one.

Comment: You probably don't want to redirect loop to the route you're currently accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Let your `ProtectedRoutes` to have a type based on their auth capabilities such as `LoginRoute` and `PrivateRoute`. Your `Profile` route acts as the login page. Therefore, it doesn't need to be user authenticated to view that page. Then create another route as `dashboard`, which will be the page user able to view in a successful log in. Now, keep your routes as follows.

```
      <Route path="/"></Route>
      <ProtectedRoute
        exact
        path="/profile"
        component={Profile}
        isAuth={isAuth}
        type="LoginRoute"
      />
      <ProtectedRoute
        exact
        path="/dashboard"
        component={() => <div>User Entered into Dashboard</div>}
        isAuth={isAuth}
        type="PrivateRoute"
      />
```

Then, you need to handle the type based authentication functionality inside your `ProtectedRoute` component as follows.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const getRouteVariables = (type, isAuth) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "LoginRoute":
      return [!isAuth, "/dashboard"];
    case "PrivateRoute":
      return [isAuth, "/profile"];
    default:
      return [isAuth, "/profile"];
  }
};

const ProtectedRoute = ({ type, isAuth, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [isRouteChanged, redirectPath] = getRouteVariables(type, isAuth);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (isRouteChanged) {
          return <Component />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: redirectPath, state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

`getRouteVariables` function return `isRouteChanged` and `redirectPath`. `isRouteChanged` means whether route needs to be changed based on `isAuth` and `redirectPath` means which path needs to be taken if redirection happens.

For `LoginRoute` type `/profile` route only comes up when `isAuth` becomes false. If `isAuth` is true, then moving to `/profile` route will redirect to `/dashboard`.

For `PrivateRoute` type `/dashboard` route only possible to access when `isAuth` becomes true. If `isAuth` is false, then moving to `/dashboard` route will redirect to `/profile`.